# kodi remote application touchpad

Tags: java, android, xbmc, touchpad, kodi

I made a Kodi(android version) remote app(for android users) and I want to implement a touchpad control in it. I don't really know how to do that,so I need an advice on how to start and some steps that I need to follow, from someone more advanced or someone who had already did something like that. If someone need more details I will give them with pleasure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it by myself and I want to show how I done it.

First I made an ImageView:

```
 <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/white_with_frame"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/touchPad" />
```

Then I made the functionality

```
imageViewPad.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            // deactivate the moving of the parent element when the touchpad is touch
            imageViewPad.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    touchpadOnActionDown(event);
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    touchpadOnActionMove(event);
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    touchpadOnActionUp(event);
                    break;
                }

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I have also the method `private void touchpadOnActionMove(MotionEvent event)`
where I determinate the direction and when I know it I call a specific function from Kodi.